# Iterate over javascript object such that key variables are used as methods to call the object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I'm hard-coding new properties into my javascript application and its a horrible code smell but I just don't know any better when it comes to javascript implementation. This is what my code looks like now:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $("#total_population_2013").html(data.table.total_population_2013);
  $("#median_age_2013").html(data.table.median_age_2013);
  //ETCETERA, FOR A VERY LONG TIME I MIGHT ADD
});
```

Its a ruby OpenStruct object converted into json that I'm sending to the getJSON method. Trial and error solution, but I can access its properties as shown above.

I'm about to add many more variables that I'll be writing into html id tags, and would prefer to do this is a more professional manner. Here is what I've tried so far but is not working:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  for(var k in data) {
    var value = data[k];
    var id_str = "#"+k;
    $(id_str).html(value);
  });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: can you give an example of the JSON and possibly an example of what a possible outcome might be?

Comment: it looks as though you should be looping through data.table:  for(var k in data.table){

Comment: from your example, it seems you should use `k in data.table` instead of just `k in data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice two things. One is that `for..in` iterates over all properties of an object, which can include stuff that it gets from the prototype chain. This is typically not what you want,  so you want to do this instead:

```
for(var k in data) if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {

   ...

}
```

This makes sure you only get the object's own properties.

Second, your JSON seems to have its data under `data.table` and instead you're pulling stuff just out of `data`. This means, you'll just get `table` as a value and you probably don't have anything with the id `#table`. I suspect you want:

```
for(var name in data.table) if (data.table.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    $("#" + name).html(data.table[name]);
}
```

Comment: Oh that's nice, I'd never clocked the fact you can use the `if (...hasOwnProperty...)` as the single statement on the `for` to avoid ending up with two lots of `{ }` and associated indentation.  +1 for that alone!

Comment: @JamesThorpe Someone on SO showed me that a while back on a question I asked, and I've used it ever since!

Comment: This actually didn't work out of the box. I had to redeclare data as `data = data.table` to get it to work like it should. Thank you though! Onward and upward